# Does the bold sentence mean Theodora can identify the cards using her some sort of psychic power, without even seeing them?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

Theodora's world was one of delight and soft colors; she had come onto Dr. Montague's list because-going laughing into the laboratory, bringing with her a rush of floral perfume-**she had somehow been able, amused and excited over her own incredible skill, to identify correctly eighteen cards out of twenty, fifteen cards out of twenty, nineteen cards out of twenty, held up by an assistant out of sight**.

context: These are excerpts from a book entitled The Haunting of Hill House. A doctor planned to invite some participants who had an experience of phenomenon before to the haunted house for investigation. Theodora one of of the people that was on the doctor's list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it means exactly what you said.

Answer (score 1):

In the full context as you have explained it, yes, I would take that to mean that Theodora has some sort of magical or psychic powers.

If the same sentence occurred outside the context of ghosts, etc, I would wonder if it meant that she was able to read the cards by magic or if it meant that the cards were marked, or she used some trick (like seeing them in a mirror or getting signals from an accomplice), etc.